cannot execute binary file on red hat
I'm running Oracle's Red Hat 7.9, and I'm encountering a problem when I run cmake --version. I've attached a screenshot with the error message.bash: /usr/local/bin/cmake: cannot execute binary file
I wanted to install something and it needed cmake, so I tried to install it with the .sh file

Firstly, text output should be pasted into questions as pre-formatted text blocks. Secondly, how did you install CMAKE? Are you sure that it's the suitable version for your machine?
